# How do I make my Discord bot change status every 10 seconds?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I have a smol Discord bot (with discord.js-commando), I have this code:

```
var activevar = ["with the &help command.", "with the developers console", "with some code", "with JavaScript"];
var activities = activevar[Math.floor(Math.random()*activevar.length)];
client.on('ready', () => {
    client.user.setActivity(activities);
}
```

But that only changes it when I restart the bot. Can someone help me out here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Program Description & Purpose:** When the bot goes online, every ten seconds, randomly select a random activity from the list of activities and update the bot with the new activity:

```js
const activities = [
    "with the &help command.",
    "with the developers console.",
    "with some code.",
    "with JavaScript."
];

client.on("ready", () => {
    // run every 10 seconds
    setInterval(() => {
      // generate random number between 0 and length of array.
      const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * activities.length);
      const newActivity = activities[randomIndex];

      client.user.setActivity(newActivity);
    }, 10_000);
});
```

**Material to consider:**

- https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/ClientUser?scrollTo=setActivity
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random

Comment: It needs a ); at the end XD

Comment: client.user.setActivity does not work these days anymore, you should replace client with bot ;)

Comment: javascript arrays are 0 based, not 1 based, index should be just Math.floor(Math.random() * activities_list.length)

Answer (score 2):

I changed it so you can change the status from playing to watching or listening.

```
const activities_list = [
    "For Rule Breakers", 
    "The purple names",
    "#general", 
    "The mods do their job"
    ]; // creates an arraylist containing phrases you want your bot to switch through.

client.on('ready', () => {
    setInterval(() => {
        const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (activities_list.length - 1) + 1); // generates a random number between 1 and the length of the activities array list (in this case 5).
        client.user.setActivity(activities_list[index], { type: 'WATCHING' }); // sets bot's activities to one of the phrases in the arraylist.
    }, 10000); // Runs this every 10 seconds.
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This will also work on v13 too.

```js
const statuses = [
  { name: "to nothing", type: "LISTENING" },
  { name: "something", type: "PLAYING" },
  { name: "your commands", type: "WATCHING" },
];
client.on("ready", () => {
  setInterval(() => {
    var randomStatus = statuses[Math.floor(Math.random() * statuses.length)];
    client.user.setActivity(randomStatus);
  }, 10000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering how often this is viewed, I thought that I'd provide an updated and clearer response.

```js
const state = 0;
const presences = [
    { type: 'PLAYING',  message: 'a game'  },
    { type: 'WATCHING', message: 'a video' }
];

setInterval(() => {
    state = (state + 1) % presences.length;
    const presence = presences[state];

    client.user.setActivity(presence.message, { type: presence.type });
}, 10000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested, but it should work in theory. It not, try to figure out what is wrong, it's good practice. Otherwise, let me know

```
client.on("ready", function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        var actID = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(activevar.length));
        client.user.setActivity(activities);
    }, 10000)
});
```

Comment: Declaring the variable `interval` has no use in this case.

Comment: In this case, no. But it can still be used

Answer (score 0):

changes every 10s for playing, watching, listening activities

```js
const activities_list = [
    { type: 'PLAYING',  message: 'a game'  },
    { type: 'WATCHING', message: 'a video' },
    { type: 'LISTENING', message: 'a music' }
];

client.on('ready', () => {
    setInterval(() => {
        const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (activities_list.length - 1) + 1);

        client.user.setActivity(activities_list[index].message, { type: activities_list[index].type });
    }, 10000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm use discord.js v12.

```
client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log(`ok`);

    const who = ["hi", "hello"];

    setInterval(() => {
        const burh = Math.floor(Math.random() * who.length);    
        client.user.setPresence({ activity: { name: who[burh]}, status: 'dnd'}); 
    }, 5000);  
});
```