# How to make my discord bot status change every 10 seconds?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I want my bots status to change every 10 seconds. This is my Discord bots status code.

```
client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as Reddit Bot`);
  client.user.setPresence({ activity: { name: 'r.help!'}, status: 'dnd' })
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error);
});
```

I want other names to be customizable aswell.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make my Discord bot change status every 10 seconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51180927/how-do-i-make-my-discord-bot-change-status-every-10-seconds)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fist you need to create a list of activities. I will call it Activities_List. Note you can call it anything you would like. You can also add as many as you would like.

```
const activities_list = [
    "Activitie One", 
    "Activitie Two", 
    "Activitie Three", 
    ];
```

Then we would create the timer that changes the activity ever 60 sec. This will also pick one of the activities we have set in the activities list and display it.

```
client.on('ready', () => {
    setInterval(() => {
        const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (activities_list.length - 1) + 1);
        client.user.setActivity(activities_list[index], {type: 'WATCHING'});
    }, 60000);
});
```

You can always change the 60000 out for 10000 which is ten seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Before you ask these kinds of questions, look on the Internet to see if you can find your answer.
Code

```
    const activities_list = [
        "with the &help command.", 
        "with the developers console",
        "with some code", 
        "with JavaScript"
        ]; // creates an arraylist containing phrases you want your bot to switch through.
    
    bot.on('ready', () => {
        setInterval(() => {
            const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (activities_list.length - 1) + 1); // generates a random number between 1 and the length of the activities array list (in this case 5).
            bot.user.setActivity(activities_list[index]); // sets bot's activities to one of the phrases in the arraylist.
        }, 10000); // Runs this every 10 seconds.
    });
```

**Source**
[How do I make my Discord bot change status every 10 seconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51180927/how-do-i-make-my-discord-bot-change-status-every-10-seconds)

Comment: deprecated Lolol LL